# try/catch in php not printing anything out

Tags: php

Hey Everyone it has been awhile wince I've worked with try/catch blocks but I would like to start using them again just for purpose of error handling and proper practices. My code is below,

```
    $email_code = $_REQUEST['code']; //retrive the code from the user clicked link in the email
    //database information
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=primarydb';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    try {

        //option for PDO allows for prepared SQL statements that will mazimize the prevention of sql injections and malicious attacks on the server and databases
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); //establish the connection
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); //disable the php parse from parsing the statements.
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //allow error mode to be active in order to display any errors which may open up holes to attacks
        //if the connection fails the try/catch block will pick it up
        if (!$conn) {
            throw new PDOException('Fatal error on connection');
        } else {
            //prepare and exexcute the query to match the codes up
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email_code, active from primarydb.user WHERE email_code = ?");
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $email_code, PDO::PARAM_STR, 32);
            //check to make sure that the statment executes properly
            if (!$stmt->execute()){
                throw new PDOException("PDO ERROR ON EXECUTION:\n" . $stmt->errorInfo());
            } else { //statement has not failed
                //get the row count
                $count = $stmt->rowCount();
                //traverse the results
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    //there can only be one!
                    if ($count != 1 || $row['active'] != 0) {
                        //generate error message
                        throw new PDOException("Wrong Code");       
                    } else {
                        echo "working";
                        //prepare the update statement
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE primarydb.user SET active = ? WHERE email_code = ?");
                        $stmt->brindParam(1, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $stmt->bindParam(2, $email_code, PDO::PARAM_STR, 32);
                        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                            throw new PDOException("We're sorry but we can not update your profile at this time, plesae try again later. If this problem persists please contact customer service.");
                        } else {
                            print "Your account has now been activated and it is ready to use!";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        //display error message if the database has failed in some manner
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I would like to know why I am not getting any of the error messages, and then how do I fix this problem so that I can avoid making the same problems again in the future. If there is something that is missing or if more information is needed please let me know. Otherwise I think it is pretty straight forward.

ADDITIONAL INFO: I have putt a message that says working at each block of if/else and the one it finally stops showing up at is when I check `if($count != 1 || $row['active'] != 0)`

UPDATE

```
<?php
    $email_code = $_REQUEST['code']; //retrive the code from the user clicked link in the email
    //database information
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=primarydb';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    try{
        //option for PDO allows for prepared SQL statements that will mazimize the prevention of sql injections and malicious attacks on the server and databases
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); //establish the connection
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); //disable the php parse from parsing the statements.
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //allow error mode to be active in order to display any errors which may open up holes to attacks
        //prepare the update statement
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE primarydb.user SET active = ? WHERE email_code = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam('is', $a = 1, $email_code);
        if($stmt->execute()){           
            print "Your account has now been activated and it is ready to use!";
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        //display error message if the database has failed in some manner
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Generated new code, I don't want to get off topic, but I would like a complete solution to this problem. I am now getting the following error

`Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mjsite\login\complete_registration.php on line 14
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031`

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on?

Comment: I do, and nothing is showing up, I haven't received any Parse errors or anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this first line from the PDOException documentation:

> Represents an error raised by PDO. You should not throw a PDOException
>   from your own code.

Just throw and catch regular old `Exception`s.  This would also catch a PDOException which inherits from it.

This also gives you a much better way to distinguish between actual exception thrown by PDO and your own exceptions.  By the way, it would seem you have a number of cases where you are redundantly throwing exception when PDO would have encountered an error and thrown an exception anyway.  Only the first exception will be caught, so in many of those cases, your throw would never be executed.

Also why bother with the SELECT before the update at all?  YOu are basically just wasting a query because you aren't doing anything with the selected information.  Perhaps just go straigth for update and handle cases where email_code doesn't exist.

Comment: Your answer is sort of helpful for me but other than the one redundancy of the select statement I'm not seeing what you're getting at with the other stuff.

Comment: @MarkHill The bottom line is that you should not be throwing `PDOException` and that, since you are running PDO in exception mode.  Your errors that you are checking for and then throwing exceptions for would have already had an exception thrown by PDO itself before there is ever an opportunity to get to your code where you throw the exception.

Comment: oh, okay, so as long as everything is done within the try enclosure, any error thrown by my $stmt variable will be caught regardless?

Comment: @MarkHill WIth PDO set to `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` rather than errors, `PDOException`s will be thrown.  These obvioulsy won't give the messaging you are looking for, but in your catch block you can inspect the Exception error code/message and provide user firendly messaging as needed based on this.

Comment: ah okay, I see how that is working now! Thank you so much one more thing though, I have edited the code above would you mind taking one final look? you have been an excellent teacher thus far!

Comment: You are using `bindParam()` improperly. You can only bind one parameter at a time (as opposed to how it is done in mysqli, which seems to be the syntax you are trying to use here).  Try `$stmt->bindParam(1, $a=1, PDO::PARAM_INT); $stmt->bindParam(2,$email_code,PDO::PARAM_STR);` I would not though that since you are are just executing the statmement onec, you could just as easily use `bindValue()` or pass parameter array to `execute()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65533/discussion-between-mark-hill-and-mike-brant).